# Integrating an expanding sphere (hollow) over a ball (solid)?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

[image: 2D shell integrating over a 3D ball, orange/intersection = dS]

So I want to integrate this blue surface from R-r to R+r (over the red ball) but I have trouble defining the surface element.

Comment: I don't think you explained the problem well. What exactly is the question? Not what you are doing, but what the problem asks you to do.

Comment: There's no specific problem. I just want to know how to find this particular intersection element.

If it makes it easier you can think of it as finding the volume of the red ball.

Comment: How the intersection is relevant? Integrate from R to R+r and multiply by 2.